# How to create questionn through the Graph API with objects?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create questions using [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) where options are my app objects(webpages).

Example:

Question: Which program should I watch?

- Option1: program1 - `// http://www.example.com/programs/1`
- Option2: program2 - `// http://www.example.com/programs/2`

The [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/question#options) of documentation page only show creating option with text.

Edit:

Is impossible to add [custom objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects) to questions through the [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't a supported use-case of the Questions API - you can use URLs as the text of the Question's options, but they won't be linked when displayed on Facebook.